# Set Layout Page of Component Dynamically or Conditionally in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I have two layout home layout and details layout and I want to assign layout page conditionally to component. Is it possible or any work around?

For example, if the session has expired then login windows layout page set conditionally like if user is inside details layout then pass details layout otherwise home layout.

Comment: Before that, you can read the document first, or give us the sample code of the relevant project:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/layouts?view=aspnetcore-5.0